# Serving static files with presigned URLs

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, static-files

I have a Django application hosted in AWS Lightstail and its static and media files hosted in a S3 bucket.

The client is asking me to serve ALL the files (static and media) through AWS's presigned URLs.

To my knowledge, presigned URLs are more suitable for media or single files rather than all the website's static files, since every time someone access the website, a new URL is generated for each static file, causing loading delays and misusage of the URLs' expiration time. I suggested to set up CloudFront instead.

My question: Is the client's request reasonable? And if so, is there a way to serve these static files in a way that the presigned URLs are not created with every new access to the website?

Comment: Are these static assets going to be publicly available or behind some kind of authentication?

Comment: You can always ask them if they are happy to pay extra for the coding and whether they are willing to have a slightly slower experience! But on the serious side, start by asking them for their _goals_ (the 'why') rather than the 'how'. Perhaps they don't want the files scraped. Frankly, generating a pre-signed URL is pretty quick and doesn't require an API call to AWS. However, it means that the pages themselves must be dynamic and can't be treated as static assets.

Comment: There's also a it of a technical challenge: you have to serve *something* to the client to handle the process of authenticating.  so "ALL the files" doesn't really compute.  You could serve *most* of them with presigned URLs but you'll need an application layer in the middle to handle presigning the URLs.

Comment: Your client's request doesn't seem to be reasonable if I understood everything correctly. However, if you client need to make all requests authenticated you probably might want to concider implementing a CloudFront + Lambda.Edge in order achieve this without having a huge overhead.